# Extract data and rename each iteration in loop

Tags: matlab

I have created a color map:

```
Color map=jet(40)
```

From this I want to use a loop to extract each row of the colormap as 40 separate matrix (vector) with the title rgb1-rgb40. How to do this?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Comment: Don't do this. People ask how to do this a lot (see duplicates above), and best practice is to break up your matrix and store it in a different way (like in a cell array or structure) or create some indexing function to make it easier to fetch what you need from your matrix.

Comment: Please don't do this. Surely `map(1,:)`-`map(40,:)` is better than having 40 separate variables that you can't (easily) loop over and you have to hardcode everywhere you used them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to execute a dynamically created string as follow:

```
map=jet(40)
for i=1:size(map, 1)
  eval(['rgb', num2str(i), '= map(', num2str(i), ', :)']);
end
```

**Warning:** Note that converting your matrix to 40 vectors in this way is probably not the most elegant solution for what you try to obtain. For more information, see [Alternatives to the eval Function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).